# Flutter iPhone: Repeated haptic feedback vibrate

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, haptic-feedback

I want the phone to buzz repeatedly.  The problem is that even though I make multiple calls to HapticFeedback.vibrate, the phone only buzzes once.  I have made sure to do the subsequent calls in a .then block, so the next call only fires after the previous call has finished.

Does anyone have a method for reliably doing repeated, chained haptic feedback calls using flutter?  The best I've been able to do is a hack - make a haptic call, sleep for a second and then do another call.  However, isn't good enough.  The sleep duration for this to work probably varies across handsets (I want to work on android and ios).

Does someone have a suggestion for how to get this to work without sleep?  I've been testing this on an iPhone 14 Pro.

```
HapticFeedback.vibrate()
    .then((value) => HapticFeedback.vibrate()
    .then((value) => HapticFeedback.vibrate()));
```